# Why is my Cython C function 40X slower than the build-in function it wraps?

Tags: performance, cython

I am new to Cython. Why is my C function `Numeraire`, which at this point simply wraps a build-in function, so much slower than calling the built-in function directly?

Thanks. Here's the Cython code (`backward.pyx`) code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from libc.math cimport exp

cdef double Numeraire(int i1, int i0, np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] j):
    cdef float rate = 0.05
    return exp(-rate/12*(i1 - i0))

def Slow(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] values, int i1, int i0):
    cdef float norm = 0.25
    cdef int i, j0, j1
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] j = np.empty(2, dtype=np.int)
    for i in range(i1-1, i0-1, -1):
        for j0 in range(i+1):
            j[0] = j0
            for j1 in range(i+1):
                j[1] = j1
                values[j0, j1] += (
                    values[j0+1, j1  ] +
                    values[j0  , j1+1] +
                    values[j0+1, j1+1])
                values[j0, j1] *= norm*Numeraire(i+1, i, j)      #4.397s (!)

def Fast(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] values, int i1, int i0):
    cdef float norm = 0.25
    cdef int i, j0, j1
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] j = np.empty(2, dtype=np.int)
    for i in range(i1-1, i0-1, -1):
        for j0 in range(i+1):
            j[0] = j0
            for j1 in range(i+1):
                j[1] = j1
                values[j0, j1] += (
                    values[j0+1, j1  ] +
                    values[j0  , j1+1] +
                    values[j0+1, j1+1])
                values[j0, j1] *= norm*exp(-0.05/12*((i+1) - i)) #0.327s
```

and here's the timing info:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import backward
In [3]: factors=2
In [4]: i=360
In [5]: %timeit backward.Fast(np.ones([i+1]*factors), i, 0)
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop
In [6]: %timeit backward.Slow(np.ones([i+1]*factors), i, 0)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.67 s per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the `ndarray` you're passing to Numeraire and not using. If you run `cython -a backward.pyx` and look at the code you see first that the `cdef double Numeraire...` line is highlighed light yellow (showing that Cython is doing hidden work there) and when you click on the line you get the following code

```
static double __pyx_f_8backward_Numeraire(int __pyx_v_i1, int __pyx_v_i0, CYTHON_UNUSED PyArrayObject *__pyx_v_j) {
  float __pyx_v_rate;
  __Pyx_LocalBuf_ND __pyx_pybuffernd_j;
  __Pyx_Buffer __pyx_pybuffer_j;
  double __pyx_r;
  __Pyx_RefNannyDeclarations
  __Pyx_RefNannySetupContext("Numeraire", 0);
  __pyx_pybuffer_j.pybuffer.buf = NULL;
  __pyx_pybuffer_j.refcount = 0;
  __pyx_pybuffernd_j.data = NULL;
  __pyx_pybuffernd_j.rcbuffer = &__pyx_pybuffer_j;
  {
    __Pyx_BufFmt_StackElem __pyx_stack[1];
    if (unlikely(__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate(&__pyx_pybuffernd_j.rcbuffer->pybuffer, (PyObject*)__pyx_v_j, &__Pyx_TypeInfo_nn___pyx_t_5numpy_int_t, PyBUF_FORMAT| PyBUF_STRIDES, 1, 0, __pyx_stack) == -1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 9; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
  }
  __pyx_pybuffernd_j.diminfo[0].strides = __pyx_pybuffernd_j.rcbuffer->pybuffer.strides[0]; __pyx_pybuffernd_j.diminfo[0].shape = __pyx_pybuffernd_j.rcbuffer->pybuffer.shape[0];
/* … */
  /* function exit code */
  __pyx_L1_error:;
  { PyObject *__pyx_type, *__pyx_value, *__pyx_tb;
    __Pyx_ErrFetch(&__pyx_type, &__pyx_value, &__pyx_tb);
    __Pyx_SafeReleaseBuffer(&__pyx_pybuffernd_j.rcbuffer->pybuffer);
  __Pyx_ErrRestore(__pyx_type, __pyx_value, __pyx_tb);}
  __Pyx_WriteUnraisable("backward.Numeraire", __pyx_clineno, __pyx_lineno, __pyx_filename, 0);
  __pyx_r = 0;
  goto __pyx_L2;
  __pyx_L0:;
  __pyx_L2:;
  __Pyx_RefNannyFinishContext();
  return __pyx_r;
}
```

where the main body of the function goes in the bit marked `/* … */`.

Some of that work happens for every Cython call, but quite a bit of it related to your unused ndarray, `j` (e.g. `__pyx_pybuffer_j`, `__pyx_pybuffernd_j`)

If you remove `j` from the list of arguments then the speed is the same with and without the function call. There's a number of options if you actually need `j` for the non-trivial, non-example version of the function.

1. If you always know 'j' is going to be length 2, you could just have

   `cdef double Numeraire(int i1, int i0, double j0, double j1):`
2. Alternatively you could pass it a C-style `double*`, a length and possibly a stride (but if you declare `j` as `cdef ndarray[...,mode="c"]` you don't need that) which will probably be faster.
3. **Best option:** the easiest option is you use the [new-style Cython typed memoryview interface](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) instead of the `ndarray` interface.

code:

```
cdef double Numeraire(int i1, int i0, long[::1] j):
  # code as before

# then within your calling function
  # ...
  cdef long[::1] j = np.empty(2, dtype=np.int)
  # ...
```

This seems to be almost overhead free in this case (however, in some other cases I've found the memoryview interface fractionally (~1%) slower, so it isn't always the best answer).